# Depth Pass to Pixel Projection (AN)

Tags: animation-nodes

*Additional question to [3DSinghVFX's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/212304/2214)*

---

To illustrate question - imagine this white/pink rectangles as rendered image of 6 x 3 pixels.
Here seen by Camera.

[image]

Animation Node tree (mentioned in the answer) generates a compact surface.

[image]

My question is ...
**How can be pixels** (reconstructed in 3D space from Depth Pass or Point Position Map as points) **represented by unconnected quads orientated to Camera. To be seen by Camera as regular squares without gaps so final result is identical to original image.**

In theory, since those faces aka pixels are oriented to camera they are still squares and from mentioned answer also grid is nicely even to a camera view ... So the only question here is probably how calculate size according to distance from camera.

[image]

**Sidenote:** Surface generated by mentioned answer is awesome, downside of that menthod are connections between front-back pixels that are empty space in real. Since there is not a way to store this kind of data in EXR, it seems to be better use pixels as separated to get [similar result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGXPZ.png).

---

I'm also interested in version with coloured Points (spheres) scaled accordingly to Camera distance, to be seen by camera as same size.

[image]

[image]

I would appreciate if you can use the same EXR source data from original Q.
Thank you for help.

[image]

Comment: @3DSinghVFX Now I see I could simplify whole the roman here into a singl question ... how to calculate size according to distance from camera?

Comment: @vkidu Hi. Do you need spheres for Point-Cloud and scaled them according to camera distance?

Comment: Okay. I have done some tests with spheres, it looks promising. However, with planes to get an exact match with the original image, we have to stretch/shear them accordingly which is difficult.

Comment: Very Sorry, I was very busy. There is a way, I'll answer this today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**Method:**

1. The idea is to first compute the distance from the camera for all vertices of a polygon 2) then find the vertex that minimum distance from the camera 3) then project the remaining vertices of the polygon accordingly.

1. Follow the *[Method for Depth Map with AN+EN](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210536/depth-pass-to-point-cloud-with-an/212304#212304)* to get this node-tree,
   [image]
2. We compute the distance from the camera for all vertices of each polygon then reproject according to the vertex that has minimum distance from the camera. This will give a new polygon(s) that is perpendicular to the camera view,
   [image]
3. Now, we have vertices for separated polygons and we can get polygon-indices and edge-indices with the help of the *Separate Polygons* node,
   [image]
   [image]

Blend File:
[image]

---

4. To add spheres at the center of newly project polygons, first, we have to compute the *scale* according to the polygon size like so,
   [image]
5. Then use *Extract Polygon Transforms* node to get the polygon transformation and use the Step 4 *scale* for matrices to instance spheres at the polygons' center,
   [image]
   [image]

Blend File:
[image]

Comment: WOW ... Thanks a lot for your time ... awesome result ... my toy for this weekend. I don't have ambition to understand the math behind ... I would be happy if I will be able to reuse it for my needs :) That seems to be easy.

Comment: You're welcome :) This method is performance-heavy. If I find some faster method then I'll add that too.