# Pointclouds from rendered depth images do not align

Tags: python, point-clouds, depth-map

I am trying to render multiple RGB-D images of a given object in Blender 2.93 using the python interface. The scene contains a single object at position [0, 0, 0] and I am rotating a camera around it on the unit sphere. When I am generating the point clouds from the depth images, they do not align (see images below). Does Blender add an offset to the depth?
[image]

**EDIT:**
I don't think the issue here lies with the inverse projection method. If this were the case, points would show bending artifacts, which is not the case. I have also overloaded the original mesh with the generated point cloud and this shows a clear downward/inward shift, which to me indicates a parameter that is internally computed in blender but not reflected in the intrinsic camera matrix that I am saving to file to compute the point cloud.

[image]

I have attached a minimal code example of loading the depth data and generating the point cloud from it below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
import cv2


def get_rays_np(H, W, K, c2w):
    i, j = np.meshgrid(
        np.arange(W, dtype=np.float32), np.arange(H, dtype=np.float32), indexing="xy"
    )
    dirs = np.stack(
        ((i - K[0, 2]) / K[0, 0], (j - K[1, 2]) / K[1, 1], np.ones_like(i)), axis=-1
    )
    rays_d = np.sum(
        dirs[..., np.newaxis, :] * c2w[:3, :3], -1
    )  # dot product, equals to: [c2w.dot(dir) for dir in dirs]
    # Translate camera frame's origin to the world frame. It is the origin of all rays.
    rays_o = np.broadcast_to(c2w[:3, -1], np.shape(rays_d))
    return np.concatenate((rays_o, rays_d), axis=-1)


base_path = "./images/30b9882d1d75be3537678474be485ca/"

img_files = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(base_path, "rgb", "rgb_*")))
mask_files = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(base_path, "rgb", "mask_*")))
depth_files = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(base_path, "rgb", "depth_*")))
pose_files = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(base_path, "pose", "*.npy")))

K = np.load(os.path.join(base_path, "intrinsics.npy"))
for ii in range(1, n_views):
    img = cv2.imread(img_files[ii]) / 255.0
    mask = (cv2.imread(mask_files[ii], cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) / 255.0).astype(int)
    depth = cv2.imread(depth_files[ii], cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
    c2w = np.load(os.path.join(pose_files[ii]))
    H, W = depth.shape

    # Create the point cloud

    depth = depth.reshape(-1)
    rays = get_rays_np(H, W, K, c2w)

    u = np.arange(0, W)
    v = np.arange(0, H)
    u, v = np.meshgrid(u, v)
    u, v = u.reshape(-1), v.reshape(-1)
    fx, fy = K[0, 0], K[1, 1]
    cx, cy = K[0, 2], K[1, 2]

    uv = np.stack((u, v, np.ones_like(u)), axis=-1)
    xy = (np.linalg.inv(K) @ np.transpose(uv)) * depth[None, :]
    x = np.transpose(xy)[:, 0]
    y = np.transpose(xy)[:, 1]

    # Get distance along the ray from z-depth
    dist = np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + depth.reshape(-1) ** 2)

    rays = rays.reshape(-1, 6)
    rays0, raysd = rays[:, :3], rays[:, 3:]

    # Normalize ray direction
    raysd = raysd / np.linalg.norm(raysd, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    pts = rays0 + raysd * (dist[:, None])

    indices = np.where(mask.reshape(-1))
    pts = pts[indices]
    colors = img.reshape(-1, 3)[indices]

    frame = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_coordinate_frame(0.1).transform(c2w)
    pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(pts)
    pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(colors)
    pcds.append(pcd)
    pcds.append(frame)
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries(pcds)
```

Comment: related / duplicated ??? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/211600/2214

Comment: Hi Nicolai, I also face same issue, have you solved it?