# Need WORLD XYZ from Camera x/y/depth

Tags: python, scripting, camera, coordinates

Currently using location_3d_to_region_2d within a script to get the screen-space coordinates of each vertex.

I need to do the reverse -- given a Cam and X/Y/depth get X,Y,Z world space.

I've encountered quite a few functions that do it with a view, but I'm working from a script_view/CLI.

How can I find WORLD xyz from a script?

Comment: Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/205152/19156

Comment: Use [`region_2d_to_location_3d`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_extras.view3d_utils.html#bpy_extras.view3d_utils.region_2d_to_location_3d)? Or build a location matrix in camera-local space space by projecting rectilinearly, and multiply it by the camera's world matrix.

Comment: lemon - that link looks like it's in the ball park.