# Obtaining real Z depth map of a scene not clipped

Tags: depth-map

This question has been posted many times, but it is impossible to do something working with the new versions of Blender.

I am trying to obtain the real depth map of a scene, meaning that I need to have as output a file containing for each pixel the real distance from the camera. I tried to put the output file format to OpenEXR, but everytime I cannot obtain the depth values. I have tried to use the 'Compositing' pannel, or in a simplier way to use the 'Output properties' pannel. Everytime, I only have a RGBA datafile, even if the 'Z-buffer' option is marked. It seems that this option does not work properly...

***EDIT :*** Thanks to *@lemon* and [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/204886/122224), I was able to obtain it! But the values are clipped to 6.5504e4... I also obtain a file with 3 channels, the three of them being exactly equal. How can I obtain a file where the values are not clipped?

Comment: not sure this is exactly what you need, but if it helps : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/205152/19156

Comment: With OpenEXR, I assume you mean Multilayer EXR and then you opened it in a software that supports multiple layers like Blender, AE or Nuke. right?

Comment: @lemon I am almost there, thanks! But the values obtained are limited to 6.55e4... Even if I am incresing the 'Clip End' of the camera...

Comment: just a guess, but that can be tried: setting the color management to "raw" (I don't know if blender uses it before writting to the file when using depth).

Comment: EXR files do not save any color transforms. Those are raw values. Might the issue be precision of 32bit float format that the values are stored in? It can hold about 7 significant digits in a decimal number before precision issues begin. You cannot use more precision in Blender it is limited to 32bit floats pretty much for everything.